# Is there an upper limit when using select in Go?

Tags: select, go

When I use select in Go, how many cases could I listen? Is there an upper limit on it, for example, 10k? Will overmuch cases bring harmful effects?

Comment: Ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. What specifically do you want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no practical upper limit.

Comment: Interesting. Did you mean _theoretical_ limit? Honest question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that there is. However, `select`s must be written explicitly at compile-time, so unless you plan on auto-generating the code for that select statement, that sounds painful to write. If you have a big list of channels you need to select over, you should try this instead:

```
for {
    for _, c := range channels {
        select {
        case val := <-c:
            // code...
        default:
            // code...
        }
    }
}
```